# Azure Update Management: How to create a dynamic group filter using tag values that have never been assigned to a resource?

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-update-management-center

When creating a dynamic group with a filter that uses tags, how do you choose a tag value that hasn't been assigned to a resource yet?

For example, I am trying to create new patching deployment schedules based on patching windows.  A new tag called 'Patch_Window' would have values such as 'Monday-10pm' 'Tuesday-12am' 'Wednesday-10pm', etc, that would indicate when the patching would begin for that group.  There would be a dynamic group for each one of these windows.  But since this is a new solution, there aren't any VMs that have these tag values yet, so I cannot choose the tag value from the tag list.

Is there a a way I can pre-define the possible values of the tag in Azure Portal so I can choose them in the filter?  I thought this would be possible in the 'Tags' space in Azure Portal but it isn't.

The only reason Thu-8pm shows up is because I applied that tag value to a testing VM
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a a way I can pre-define the possible values of the tag in Azure Portal so I can choose them in the filter?

Yes, you can create predefined tag with a value using PowerShell.

I have followed this [MSDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-aztag?view=azps-9.7.0) to create predefined tag with a value without any resources.

> **PowerShell Script**
>
> ```
> Connect-AzAccount 
> New-AzTag -Name "Department" -Value "HR"
> ```

**Output:**

[image]

When I checked the tags in the portal, I found that although the tags were present, no resources were assigned to the particular tag.

[image]

When I tried to filter the tags in `update management`, it did not show any results

> Note:  You cannot filter by tag if no resources are associated with that tag.

[image]

Comment: "Note: You cannot filter by tag if no resources are associated with that tag."
Is this a note that you created or did this come from a document? URL?

Comment: I have tested this in my environment and have mentioned the same point.

Comment: Yes I was quoting your note and asking you if you had quoted that from another KB article or if that was your own note.